# @FXML not initalising VBox

Tags: javafx, addition, fxml, children, vbox

I have main controller and an fxml file. In my main controller I have written:

```
@FXML
public static VBox spectrumListVBox;
```

And in my fxml file I have

```
<javafx.scene.layout.VBox fx:id="spectrumListVBox" prefHeight="324.0" prefWidth="191.0" />
```

In my main controller if I was trying to add multiple panes to this vbox and having errors.  There are two things going on here.  The first is that whilst running it would return a nullPointerException which at first I assumed was the pane I was adding to it was returning null.  So I changed it to the following code. When I press a button I want it to add this new button to the vbox.

```
spectrumListVBox.getChrildren().add(new Button("Click Here");
```

However this too presented with a nullPointerException, which leads me to the conclusion that the VBox isn't being initialised by the FXML file. If I change the code in the main controller to:

```
public static VBox spectrumListVBox = new VBox();
```

This results in no warnings when compiled, however I do not actually see anything added to my vbox. I can confirm everything else is loading correctly (my controller and fxml has about 50 elements which are all hooked up and working correctly).  I have closely checked that the fx:id and the controller element name are matching, and I have tried cleaning the project in case anything else was lingering on.

Comment: You shouldn't be using class variables (`static`), but instance variables. The used FXML controller is an instance, not a class.

Comment: I cannot believe I overlooked this.  Worked first time.  It's like I keep looking for it to be something more complicated that I am not aware of rather than the basics.  Thank you